# First order PDEs and the method of characteristics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am studying PDEs using the book "*PDEs An Introduction 2nd edition*" by Walter A. Strauss. In Chapter 2, a "geometric method" is described in order to solve linear PDEs of the type:

$$ (x,y)\mapsto u_x + yu_y = 0 $$

This is said to be equivalent to the directional derivative of $u$ in the direction of the vector $(1,y)$ being set to 0. Then *characteristic curves* having as tangent vectors $(1,y)$ are found

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{1}  \implies y = Ce^x $$

Since $u(x,y)$ is constant on these curves:

$$u(x,y) = f(e^{-x}y)$$

is the general solutions of the PDE, where $f$ is an arbitrary function. Now the same method is applied to solve more general equations, such as:

$$u_x + u_y + u = f(x,y)$$

I have tried to use the same method to solve the following differential equation:

$$yu_x -xu_y = 3x$$ 
where $ u(x,0) = x^2$

Then applying the method:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-x}{y} \implies C = x^2 + y^2$$

The PDE reduces to an ODE:

$$\frac{du}{dx} = 3x/y \implies u (x,y)  = 3x^2/2y + f(C)$$

However with the boundary imposed ($u(x,0) = x^2$) this seem impossible to solve since to find the particular solution I would have to divide the a term by zero. Does the method described in the book have limited scope? How can I solve this differential equation? Also, why is $u(x,y)$ constant on the "*characteristic curves*"?

Comment: If you introduce polar coordinates $x=r\cos \theta, y=r\sin \theta$, then $y\partial_x-x\partial_y=-\partial_\theta$. This is not the method you asked but it leads to a quick integration.

Comment: Yeah that is a good trick, however I was more interested in the method and not the solution itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see where you found an impossibility or an exception in the rules.

I the case of $\quad yu_x-xu_y=3x \tag 1$

$$\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{-x}=\frac{du}{3x}$$
A first family of characteristic curves comes from $\quad\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{-u}\quad$ which leads to $$x^2+y^2=c_1$$
A second family of characteristic curves comes from $\quad\frac{dy}{-x}=\frac{du}{3x}\quad$ which leads to $$u+3y=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE $(1)$ expressed on the form of implicit equation is :
$$\Phi(x^2+y^2\:,\:u+3y)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is an arbitrary fonction of two variables.

Or equivalently, the general solution of PDE $(1)$ on explicit form is $\quad u+3y=F(x^2+y^2)$
$$u(x,y)=-3y+F(x^2+y^2)$$

where $F(X)$ is an arbitrary function of the variable $X$ with $X=x^2+y^2$.

Boundary condition : $\quad u(x,0)=x^2=F(x^2+0^2)=F(x^2)$.

So, the function $F$ is now determined : $\quad F(X)=X.\quad$ Putting it into the above general solution where $X=x^2+y^2$ leads to the particular solution which fits the boundary condition :
$$u(x,y)=-3y+(x^2+y^2)$$

OTHER EXAMPLE : $\quad u_x+u_y+u=e^{x+2y} \tag 2$
$$u_x+u_y=e^{x+2y}-u$$
$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{e^{x+2y}-u}$$
A first family of characteristic curves comes from $\quad\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{1}\quad$ which leads to $$x-y=c_1$$
A second family of characteristic curves comes from $\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{e^{x+2y}-u}=\frac{du}{e^{(c_1+y)+2y}-u}=\frac{du}{e^{c_1+3y}-u}$ 
$$\frac{du}{dy}+u=e^{c_1+3y}$$
This is a first order linear ODE easy to solve : $\quad u=\frac14 e^{c_1+3y}+c_2e^{-y}=\frac14 e^{(x-y)+3y}+c_2e^{-y}$ 
$$ue^y-\frac14 e^{x+3y}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE $(2)$ expressed on the form of implicit equation is :
$$\Phi\left((x-y)\:,\:(ue^y-\frac14 e^{x+3y})\right)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is an arbitrary fonction of two variables.

Or equivalently, the general solution of PDE $(2)$ on explicit form is from $\quad ue^y-\frac14 e^{x+3y}=F(x-y)$
$$u(x,y)=\frac14 e^{x+2y}+e^{-y}F(x-y)$$
where $F(X)$ is an arbitrary function of the variable $X=x-y$.

Comment: I believe that the author of my book seems to use a different method to solve the PDE, have a look [here](http://www.stemjock.com/STEM%20Books/Strauss%20PDEs%202e/Chapter%201/Section%202/Exercise%2010/StraussPDEch1s2p10.pdf) at an example. If you look at the last few lines of my question, there seems to be a problem (using the method used in the link)

Comment: It is fundamentally the same method, with some variant of symbols and presentation. See :https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Charpit-Lagrange+equations&title=Special:Search&profile=default&fulltext=1&searchToken=heq6kj3ipymytc4edjwsbt6u and see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics. You will have to do a bit of "gymnastic of the brain" in order to make the link. I wish you bon courage.

Comment: You can see that the general solution in the book is : $$u(x,y)=\frac14 e^{x+2y}+e^{-y}f(x-y)$$ which is exactly the same than in my answer. I will not repeat what is already in the book to determine the function $f$ according to the boundary condition. The method is the same.

Comment: Ok I will look into that. However, since you seem to be aware of the connection between the methods, in the last of part of my question did I do a mistake or is that the correct way to proceed?

Comment: $\frac{du}{dx} = 3x/y \implies u (x,y)  = 3x^2/2y + f(C)$ is false because you integrate $3x/y$ without taking account that $y$ is not constant. You cannot solve it that way. This not a correct application of the method of characteristic. One have to find two independent families of characteristic curves. You got one :$x^2+y^2=C_1$ but not a second one.

Comment: Oh that was it! I needed to use $y^2 = c-x^2$ and then integrate. Therefore
$\frac{du}{dx} = 3x/y \implies u (x,y)  = -3y + f(C)$.

Comment: I was confused by the notation $\frac{du}{dx}$ since I thought that $u$ would have "become" a function of $x$ only. That makes me wonder why isn't $y$ constant.

Comment: @daljit97 I pointed out the mistake you made about y in the differential equation... But wasnt sure about the method Strauss used

Comment: @Isham yes you are right, I was too invested into thinking about why the method led me to that point that it didn't occur to me that a simple substitution was needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have this:
$$\frac{du}{dx} = 3x/y ==> u (x,y)  = 3x^2/y + f(C)$$
Because you have a differential equation ( du,dx) but three variables namely x,y,u. Y shouldnt be there...Apart for that mistake you did a very good job.

**Usisng the method of characteristics:**

$$\frac {dx}{y}=\frac {dy}{-x}=\frac {dz}{3x}$$
$$-xdx=ydy \implies x^2+y^2=K_1$$
$$3xdy=-xdz  \implies y+z/3 =K_2$$
$$f(x^2+y^2)=y+u/3$$
$$u(x,y)=3f(x^2+y^2)-3y$$
we have $u(x,0)=x^2$
$$f(x^2)=x^2/3 \implies  f(x)=x/3$$
Therefore
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=x^2+y^2-3y}$$

Comment: Hmm in the book in order to solve $u_x + u_y + u = e^{x+2y}$ the author does setup the following equation:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + u = e^{x+2y}$ 
Would that be an exception to the rule?

Comment: @daljit97 I don't know I dont have the book right now. Thats weird that Strauss was so complicated about first order linear pde.. when it's easy to solve directly with characteristics method..

Comment: Here is the link with the exercise and the solution provided http://www.stemjock.com/STEM%20Books/Strauss%20PDEs%202e/Chapter%201/Section%202/Exercise%2010/StraussPDEch1s2p10.pdf

Comment: Oh thats another method..I dont know that method...I deleted my comments on that method you used since I was completely wrong about it...

Comment: Oh ok, could you provide a reference that explains and show why the method of characteristic works? Looking around I couldn't find anything satisfying.

Comment: It works well here but the Strauss method seems to fail here ...Maybe someone will explain why it fails and how to make it works ...Reference book oh I studied pde in an old russian book..